# How to fix the bot from asking for id in DM , discord bot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, prefix

Am coding a discord bot, the bot works fine if run inside the server but I want to add some commands that will also work inside DM, I have some code that set prefix for every server and when I run the bot and try commands in DM it produce error because it looking for guild id which DM doesn't have, how can I go around this.

```
//the code from line index.js:63:30 in the error message

if(message.author.bot) return;

let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./prefixes.json", "utf8"));
if(!prefixes[message.guild.id]){
  prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
    prefixes: botconfig.prefix
  };
}
```

I have tried using if statement but when I run command in DM the command still doesn't work but it doesn't produce any error.

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
      let prefix = "!";
} else (message.guild) {
      let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./prefixes.json", "utf8"));
  if(!prefixes[message.guild.id]){
    prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
      prefixes: botconfig.prefix
    };
  let prefix = prefixes[message.guild.id].prefixes;
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);

  let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
  if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot,message,args);
  } 
}
}
```

Below is the error am getting which is pointing me to line 63 in my code which is the code I posted above

````
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\index.js:63:30)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\episode-18-code\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
(node:2912) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2912) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
if(message.channel.type === 'dm') {
    let prefix = 'bot main prefix'
}
else if(message.channel.type === 'guild') {
      let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./prefixes.json", "utf8"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run certain things based on what type of channel it is.

```js
if (message.channel.type === 'text') {
  // Server text channel commands
}

if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
  // DM channel commands
}
```

All types of channels, according to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type)

- `dm` direct message channel
- `group` group DM channel
- `text` server text channel
- `voice` server voice channel
- `category` server category channel
- `news` server news channel
- `store` server store channel

Comment: You can also just use the same as the server prefix in DM's just make sure the commands are compatible

Comment: I used that, now am not getting an error but the command in DM is not working

Comment: @Ayodele, this is because the 'command' is `!command-name` not `command-name`, you should do `const args = message.content.trim().slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g); const command = args.shift()`

Comment: The same as in your example, with `commandfile.run(client, message, args)` (client is `bot` in your case)